# Student's id card validation system

Tags: qr-code, card

I work in a school in which every student has a personal ID card with name, surname ecc...
Since this card gives the possibility to benefit of several discounts in theatres, cinemas and shops i need to make a system which tells to merchants if the card is still valid or not (if the student does not roll in the new academic year, the card is not valid anymore).

Each student has a 6 numbers ID.

My idea is to print a QR Code on the card which contains a url that ends with the student's id, something like: https://www.school.com/students/123456
That webpage should be somehow connected to a database (or better a google sheet, easier for school's secretary) that tells the current status of id 123456.

So if database says that 123456 is valid, a green "VALID" should appear on the webpage, otherwise a RED "NOT VALID" shoul appear.

I know there are several apps that allows this kind of thing, by the way i really need to do it with urls that can be opened by anyone without the need of particular apps.

Is there any tool that i can use for doing this?
Or should i build everything from scratch? (i hope not, i'm not a coder)

Thank you very much.

I know there are several apps that allows this kind of thing, by the way i really need to do it with urls that can be opened by anyone without the need of particular apps.

Comment: Consider that if the identity is a QR with 6 digits, and anyone can publicly check the validity of a given number, it would be trivial to take over the identity of others that are valid. This may not be desired. At least make sure there are other ways to validate a given person. Maybe require a PIN when used or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, by the way the identity thief should have a pvc card printer, template and everything.

Anyway, this could be avoided by showing name and surname on the validation web page, that should correspond with the one that is written on the card. As last thing the card ownership should be checked by an official identity card with picture.